# Ruby class definitions of HTML tags

Tags: html, ruby

Is there a Ruby project that provides representations of all HTML (specifically HTML5) tags as Ruby classes?

Ideally, each class should include object attributes for the valid attributes of that HTML tag.

Comment: too vague.  What are you trying to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 1:1 relationship, but [docgenerator](http://rubygems.org/gems/docgenerator) defines HTML-tags with checks for html-attributes.

Disadvantages: not all HTML-tags defined (at least, there is no guarantee), no HTML5, no HTML-versions checked, only rare encoding checks.

Example:

```
require 'docgenerator'

h1 = element(:h1,{
    :class => 'xx',
    :undefined => 'ooops',
  }, 'title')

puts h1.to_html
```

ends with:

```
 WARN docgenerator default: Usage of unknown attribute 'undefined' in <Docgenerator::Sectioning::Section>
<h1 class = "xx" >title</h1>
```

(The warning could be suppressed, a logger is used).